# Could not write the file an assertation has failed in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using adobe extend script for exporting a file into jpg format in adobe illustrator. when i'm performing an export operation, sometimes it shows "could not write the file. an assertation has failed" but not every time.

I'm using following code

```
var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsJPEG();

            var type = ExportType.JPEG;

            var fileSpec = new File(dest);

            exportOptions.antiAliasing = true;

            exportOptions.qualitySetting = 70;

            app.activeDocument.exportFile( fileSpec, type, exportOptions );
```

Is it part of code error or anything from the side of Illustrator? it doesn't occur at all time. does it seem to an OS or version problems? Although I'm using the latest version of illustrator.

Comment: Are you exporting to the Creative Cloud folder?

Comment: nop im just trying to illustrator document to an jpeg file..